# how to replace strings before another string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this string:

```
 var str = "jquery12325365345423545423im-a-very-good-string";
```

What I would like to do, is removing the part 'jquery12325365345423545423' from the above string.

The output should be:

```
 var str = 'im-a-very-good-string';
```

How can I remove that part of the string using php? Are there any functions in php to remove a specified part of a string?

sorry for not including the part i have done

I am looking for solution in js or jquery

so far i have tried

```
var str="jquery12325365345423545423im-a-very-good-string";
str=str.replace("jquery12325365345423545423","");
```

but problem is numbers are randomly generated and changed every time.

so is there other ways to solve this using jquery or JS

Comment: Please post your code so far, explain what didn't work and what you tried to solve it.

Comment: Is it always going to be that sort of string ?

Comment: What pattern of characters are you trying to remove and/or keep?

Comment: @hitesh what do you want exactly?I think you have got confused with the definition of string. Do you want that part of string to get removed??

Comment: @hitesh I am guessing you will get more of one string, how does it change? that would change the answer, maybe `replace` is better, maybe a substring would make more sense. Also, [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You want to replace a JavaScript string in PHP?

Comment: @putvande : using JS or jquery , regex will also work

Comment: @simpleBob : sorry bob !!!! i just included the part i tried

Comment: could you please upvote the question instead of downvoting it.........thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be best to describe the methods usually used with this kind of problems and let you decide what to use (how the string changes is rather unclear).

**METHOD 1: Regular expression**

You can search for a regular expression and replace the part of the string that matches the regular expression. This can be achieved through the [JavaScript Replace() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

In your case you could use following Regular expression: `/jquery\d+/g` (all strings that begin with jquery and continue with numbers, f.e. jquery12325365345423545423 or jquery0)

As code:

```
var str="jquery12325365345423545423im-a-very-good-string";
str=str.replace("/jquery\d+/g","");
```

See the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JpS9m/)

**METHOD 2: Substring**

If your code will always have the same length and be at the same position, you should probably be using the [JavaScript substring() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp).

As code:

```
var str="jquery12325365345423545423im-a-very-good-string";
var code = str.substring(0,26);
str=str.substring(26);
```

See the [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JpS9m/1/)

Comment: Thanks i would go with REGEX ver of answer !! it is working like a charm :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution is to do it with:

```
str = str.replace(/jquery\d+/, '').replace(' ', '');
```

Comment: Keep in mind that it will only work if the string always has this format. EDIT: He now changed the post.

Comment: also wants to replace spaces

Answer (score 2):

You can use string replace.

```
var str = "jquery12325365345423545423im-a-very-good-string";
str.replace('jquery12325365345423545423','');
```

Then to removespaces you can add this.

```
str.replace(' ','');
```

Comment: also wants to replace spaces

Answer (score 0):

Run this sample in chrome dev tools

```
var str="jquery12325365345423545423im-a-very-good-string";
str=str.replace("jquery12325365345423545423","");
console.log(str)
```